# Factory pattern with private constructors in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I am trying to implement a factory pattern that consists of

- a factory class
- an abstract class with protected constructor
- inherited classes with private constructors and virtual public 
  destructors.

I want to make sure that

- No other one than the factory can not create any instance
- If a new inherited class is defined it will not require any modification on interface class and already defined inherited classes. Juts new class implementation and adding into factory classes create method.

I also do not want to write same-like code(like static factory method per inited) for every inherited class and leave the future developers much work for factory connections.

i.e with pseduo code

```
class Factory;

class Interface
{
    protected:
        Interface(){/*Do something*/};
    public:
        virtual ~Interface(){/*Do something*/}
    /*I wish I could do below and it is valid for all inherited 
    classes but friendship is not inherited in C++*/
    //friend Interface* Factory::create(Type)
};

class InheritedA:public Interface
{
    private:
        InheritedA(){/*Do something*/};
    public:
        virtual ~InheritedA(){/*Do something*/}
    /*I dont want to do below two lines for every inherited class*/
    //friend Interface Factory::create(Type)
    //public: Interface* factoryInheritedA(){return new InheritedA();}
};

class InheritedB:public Interface
{
    private:
        InheritedB(){/*Do something*/};
    public:
        virtual ~InheritedA(){/*Do something*/}
};

class Factory
{
     static Interface* create(Interface type)       
     {
           switch(type)
           {
           case A:
                return new InheritedA();
           case B:
                return new InheritedB();
           default:
                //exceptions etc
           }
     }
}

int main()
{
    Interface* I = Factory::create(A/*or B*/);
    return 0;
}
```

Above code is the cloest I put out. Any suggestions (a speciality of C++, a different design,...) is welcome.

Comment: You forgot to write a question.

Comment: Why do you need all this? Sounds Javaesque. This might be a case of the XY problem.

Comment: @UzorTuTuEjt I wrote what I want to do with the restrictions. I really can not see why a question sentence is required

Comment: A question is required, I can't see what the problem is or why you need this or what you are trying to solve

Comment: @TonyD please read the [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) of sites before you suggest migrations. This is pseudo-code and thus is off-topic on codereview.

Comment: @DanPantry: it was this question I'd have needed to read more carefully... didn't notice it was pseudo code.

Comment: @ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ X is what I wrote above the code. Y is the code. I ask about X not Y. But I also put it cuz it may be a base for answers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this a good idea, but here is a way to do this. You create a Tag type which can only be created by the Factory and make all the constructors take a parameter of that type.

```
class Factory;

class Tag
{
    Tag() {}
    friend Factory;
};

class Interface 
{
public:
    Interface(Tag t) {}
    virtual ~Interface() {}
};

struct Impl1: public Interface
{
    Impl1(Tag t): Interface(t) {}
};

class Factory
{
public:
   Interface* makeInstance()
   {
       return new Impl1( Tag{} );
   }
};

void foo()
{
    Impl1 i( Tag{} );
}
```

You will get a compiler error in `foo()` because `Tag::Tag` is private.

Comment: at least it prohibits others to create instances. it is not a solution yet but may  be a good start for it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a templated function:

```
template<typename Type>
std::unique_ptr<Interface> make_interface() {
    // exceptions etc..
}

template<>
std::unique_ptr<Interface> make_interface<InheritedA>() {
    return std::make_unique<InheritedA>();
}

template<>
std::unique_ptr<Interface> make_interface<InheritedB>() {
    return std::make_unique<InheritedB>();
}
```

but I really don't see the point in all of this Javaesque boilerplate. Not to mention that you are transforming a compile time information (the type) into a runtime one (via exceptions) for no reason really.

I would just go with:

```
std::unique_ptr<Interface> ptr_a = std::make_unique<InheritedA>();
std::unique_ptr<Interface> ptr_b = std::make_unique<InheritedB>();
```

when needed.

Comment: The template specializations might just as well be replaced by two regular functions, right?

Comment: @JorenHeit Well, no, if you want to have that `make_interface<Type>` throws an exception when `Type` is not `InheritedA` or `InheritedB`.

Comment: Why would you want that? I'd rather have a compiler error.

Comment: Where does he state that requirement? I realize that his pseudocode produces an exception, but that's not the same. It just strikes me as strange that templates are used to generate runtime errors in your solution, that' all. Smells like template over-use.

Comment: @JorenHeit To me it sounds like templates and compile time information is not used enough. OP, in his original post, asked for a way to distinguish types at runtime and eventually throwing an exception if an incorrect type was passed. That's what my code is doing, but as I described in the answer, that's not very useful.

Answer (score -8):

It is rarely a good practice to use Factory. I count it as an anti-pattern together with the Singleton. In good design, classess do not concern themselves on how they are created. In your case, when used in Factory, how do you create your class using custom allocator? On stack? In shared memory? In memory-mapped file? From the buffer? In place? This is all really hard to cover in Factory, but do not despair - the simple and elegant solution is ditch the factory!

Comment: It may be a very rare opinion to consider factory as an anti-pattern. I also cannot follow the reasoning. The point of factory as far as I understand it is to decouple clients from the creation of related objects, i.e. a client should not know what is created, or how it is created. It has nothing to do with the created objects themselves. It is exactly to enforce that "classess do not concern themselves on how they are created", which you assign as good design.

Comment: @Jens, first of all, the statement 'clients should not know how it is created' is a synonim for bad design. Clients need to be able to control how the object is created. Days of everything being simply newed in the heap are long gone. For instance, no performance-crytical application (and pity to anybody using C++ for non-performance critycal apps) would really like to create their objects using vanilla new. As simple as that. You need to provide a factory with allocator, it's a must. 

Comm. size limits my further writeup, but I am standing firm - the way factories are done usually is bad.

Comment: I don't think you get my point. Let's assume I have a class A, which uses some class hierarchy with abstract interface B with sub-classes C and D. In the class A, to be re-usable, I want to be able to customize which of C and D (or a new implementation X) is created. If I use a factory, I can do that. I can also decide on the allocation strategy by implementing another factory. Class A does not know how and what is created. I think that is good design, and most people probably agree. I also don't know how you write testable code without factories.

Comment: @Jens, I am lost at your example. If you go by original OP example, factory is absolutely useless there.

Comment: The original example does not give enough context for any judgment. He just shows an abstract interface, two implementations of it and a factory and asks how to prevent other classes than the factory from creating objects. You could also say that using interfaces is absolutely useless there, as much as using classes at all.

Comment: It's the text-book example for a factory. I have a class which creates some depdencies. There are variations for that dependency, so an interface is used. Let's say I have a class which uses a socket abstraction (an abstract interface with implementations, e.g. TCP or Unix Domain Socket). If I use a factory, I can write the class without knowing which socket type is created. I can later add new socket types, and the class does not have to be changed. I can implement mock sockets, and the class works with them. Bad design?

Comment: Or consider the example from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). I have an application which creates UI elements. With a factory, I can change the implementation of the UI elements easily, and the application does not see that. If you hard-code object creation, you have to change the complete application everywhere. Again, I could implement a testing UI for unit testing. How do you do that without a factory? The factory could also pre-allocate objects in a pool, or in a special memory area, re-use instances etc.